# Confused By MySQL Calculation

Tags: mysql

I have a question I need to answer in my "Use A Structured Query Language" module in my DB course, and I'm stuck on one of the questions.

Here's the question:

Calculate the age of horses that died and multiply it by 3 to get their comparable human age. List their horse_id, name and "human age". Order by horse_id.

Here is the query I have been trying to achieve this with but I am getting figures that are way to big to be in human age:

```
SELECT horse_id, name, died * 3
   AS 'human year'
   FROM horse
   ORDER BY horse_id;
```

Here is the horse table being used in this query along with their rows:

**HORSE TABLE STRUCTURE**

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| horse_id | int(2)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| colour   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sire     | int(4)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dam      | int(4)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| born     | int(4)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| died     | int(4)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gender   | varchar(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The output I get is as follows:

```
+----------+--------------+------------+
| horse_id | name         | human year |
+----------+--------------+------------+
|      101 | Flash        |          0 |
|      102 | Star         |          0 |
|      201 | Boxer        |          0 |
|      301 | Daisy        |          0 |
|      401 | Snowy        |       5985 |
|      501 | Bluebell     |       5979 |
|      502 | Sally        |       5994 |
|     9998 | Unknown dam  |          0 |
|     9999 | Unknown sire |          0 |
+----------+--------------+------------+
```

I'm tearing my hair out of this one, just can't seem to get the correct output and thought someone on here would have some idea.

Thanks in advance, and I hope I have provided a decent amount of info

Stu :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I divided 5985 to 3 and got 1995. So your "died" field is year. You have to subtract it from current year and then multiply by 3. Maybe something like this...

```
SELECT horse_id, name, (YEAR(CURDATE()) - died) * 3 AS 'human year'
   FROM horse
   WHERE died > 0
   ORDER BY horse_id;
```

Comment: Hi tanaydin, this is perfect. Thank you so much for this. I think I might have been looking to much into this. Seems pretty straight forward the way you've put it. Might be time for a coffee break haha. Thanks again :D